# How to recover a shuffled matrix

Tags: matrices, computational-complexity

Suppose that I have a matrix $A$. $A$ can be a rating matrix. That is, $A(i,j)$ is the rating user $i$ has given to item $j$.

Suppose that I shuffle the rows and columns of matrix $A$ and get $A_{\text{shuffle}}$.

Now, actually, both $A$ and $A_{\text{shuffle}}$ contains the same information. Because shuffling the columns or rows do not change the ratings the users give to items.

Is there an efficient way to show that $A$ and $A_{\text{shuffle}}$ contain the same users and items.

I.e., as suggested by polkjh,  given matrices $A$ and $B$, how can I check efficiently if $B$ can be obtained by shuffling rows and columns of $A$?

Thanks

Comment: Can't see anything there to "show".

Comment: Do you mean 'given matrices $A$ and $B$, check if $B$ can be obtained by shuffling rows and columns of $A$'?

Comment: To get from $A$ to $A_{shuffle}$, you use $n$ operations $o_1,\dots,o_n$. You know that all these operations "preserve the data" and you want to show that if you apply them one after the other, you "preserve the data" too. Do to that define $A_0=A$, $A_{n+1}=o_{n+1}(A)$. Then use a recurrence to show that $\forall n\in \{0\dots n\}, A_n$ contains the same data as $A_0$.

Comment: @polkjh Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Are the ratings real numbers? If the ratings are picked from some finite set, the problem will be easier.

Comment: I think a bit more information about your data model would be useful here. It's clear that shuffling the 'rows' (i.e. users) maintains plenty of useful information about individual items (average ranking, variance, etc.); but how does shuffling (unlabeled) columns maintain any useful information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is NP-problem about graph isomorphism.
What kind of algorithm you consider "efficiently"? Some polynomial algo? You can sure use some  heuristics, if you know something about $A$, but there is no polynomial algo for general case.

Comment: As I understand the question, both the columns *and* the rows got permuted. Then the problem is much harder.

Comment: Yes, it became harder, even NP. Edited my comment.

Comment: It's not (quite) graph isomorphism - that would require that the permutations of rows and columns be _linked_, and removing that constraint can at least potentially make the problem much easier.

Comment: (Also, see my notes to Azimut - Graph Isomorphism _is_ in NP, but so is every problem in P - you may mean NP-complete, and if so, then GI isn't known to be NP-complete (and is suspected not to be!), but at the same time, there's no _known_ polynomial algorithm for GI, which is a far cry from knowing there isn't one.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Why should graph isomorphism require the two permutations to be "linked"?

Comment: @azimut Because if you shuffle the columns to 'swap labels' on e.g. nodes 2 and 3, so that those nodes with a link to 2 now have a link to 3 instead and vice versa, then you also need to shuffle the rows so that the links _out_ from those nodes correspond to their relabeling.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I still don't get why should graph isomorphism require the two permutations to be "linked". If you only permute the columns that would correspond to an another graph which is isomorphic to the first one. There seems to be no need to permute any columns. A concrete example might e helpful

Comment: @AhmetYilmaz Consider the cyclic graph on 3 nodes 1->2->3->1; then the adjacency matrix is ((0 1 0) (0 0 1) (1 0 0)). Permuting columns 2 and 3, without permutimg rows,  gives the matrix ((0 0 1) (0 1 0) (1 0 0)), which is the graph with edges 1->3, 3->1 and from 2 to itself.

Comment: @Harold thanks for noticing that this is a type of graph isomorphism problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's reformulate the question:

If $A,B$ are two matrices of the same size (not necessarily square) over some alphabet, decide if there are permutation matrices $P,Q$ such that $A = PBQ$.

Though I don't remember a precise reference in the moment, I'm quite sure I've seen that this problem is NP-complete, meaning there is no efficient algorithm for this problem (assuming P $\neq$ NP).

Comment: If P and Q were required to be the same matrix (so that rows and columns are permuted together) then the problem becomes weighted graph isomorphism, whose unweighted version (i.e., all entries 0/1) is considered likely to be NP-intermediate (i.e., not in P but not NP-complete either).  Unfortunately, this doesn't prove that the given problem is hard because removing the constraint can potentially make it easier to prove.

Comment: (Also, I initially edited presuming you meant 'NP-complete' because of the rest of that sentence, but realize that that's not necessarily so - though if you _do_ mean that the problem is NP-complete (remember that all problems in P are also in NP!) then you should edit the answer yourself to say so.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Yes, I thought of NP-complete. Thank you!